# Is there a webpack loader / NPM script that compiles solely my SCSS files, similar to how Gulp works?

Tags: javascript, webpack, sass, compilation, npm-scripts

I've been using Webpack and have found it great for bundling, polyfilling and all sorts of other functions for Javascript, however I wondered if there was a known loader / NPM script that automatically compiles designated .scss files into one.

I have previously used the sass-loader, extract-css plugin to take SCSS out of components and bundle them into the final dist file which is fine for web apps.  However, a lot of my day to day work is spent working on traditional websites, so it's often not generated via components / modules.

What I'm looking for, is anytime I save an .scss file, if this is included within my entry points / rules, it automatically compiles all .scss files into a dist/styles.css sheet.

I've had a look online and Gulp seems to offer this, but it looks like Webpack already does 90% of what Gulp offers so ideally would want to keep this all in Webpack.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

import the scss file on your entry point like this `import './style.scss';`.

Install `mini-css-extract-plugin`.

Then add this to your webpack config

```js
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(sc|c)ss$/,
                use: [
                    // { loader: 'style-loader' },
                    {
                        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, // extract css to a single file
                        options: {
                            publicPath: '../',
                            hmr: false
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader', options: {
                            sourceMap: false
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'postcss-loader',
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: false,
                            plugins: [
                                require('autoprefixer')
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader', options: { sourceMap: false }
                    }
                ],
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ],
    },
```

Comment: Ah, I'd used that with component dev but hadn't thought to use just on the .scss file, thank you! I will give this a go later after work and mark if it all works :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't get this to work.  Installed all the various loaders, but it firstly was having issues with the "hmr: false", and then the 'autoprefixer' require in the postcss-loader, and then a comment came up regarding "No template for dependency: CssDependency".  That's where I left it and found an easy alternative in the Koala GUI - simple install, it watches my scss and compiles hassle free. I'll keep Webpack handling my JS as that seems the best way. Thanks for the help